# How to efficiently go over column values in one dataframe and find row in which the value occurs in other dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, alias

I have 2 Pandas dataframes.

```
df1:
   stringColumn
0     see ya
1     yo
2     mkey


df2:
    name       alias1      alias2
0  goodbye    see ya      bye
1  OK          cool        mkey
2  hello       hey         yo
```

I would like to, in a efficient way, to go through the column values in the df1['stringColumn'], search for the row index where the value from df1 occurs in the df2 and exchange it with the corresponding value from the df2['name'] columns.

The end result would be:

```
df1:
   stringColumn
0     goodbye
1     hello
2     OK
```

Currently I am doing:

```
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        row['stringColumn'] = df2[df2.apply(lambda rowAlias: rowAlias.astype(str).str.contains(row['stringColumn'], case=False).any(), axis=1)]['name'].values[0]
```

It's working but it's reeeeeally slow, especially since I have ~5000 rows in df1 and around 100 rows and 10 columns in df2.

There must be something simpler and quicker then this monstrosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do `merge` after `melt`

```
s=df1.merge(df2.melt('name'),left_on='stringColumn',right_on='value',how='left')[['stringColumn','name']]
s
  stringColumn     name
0        seeya  goodbye
1           yo    hello
2         mkey       OK
```

Comment: Spot on. Much faster solution then that monstrosity of mine. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'c11':[1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'c21':[11,12,13], 'c22':[1,2,3]})

df1.loc[df2['c22']==df1['c11'],'c11'] = df2['c21']
```

df2['c22']==df1['c11'] this condition is to check values of columns of df1 and df2 and 'c11' is new column created in df1 by loc method and RHS value is assigned to that column. **This solution will not work if column lengths of df1 and df2 are different.It will give error.** 
Upvote if this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case, I have multiple columns with aliases in df2 and I have to search the string value from the df1 in all of them.

Comment: You can put or condition like this df2['c22']==df1['c11']  | df2['c23']==df1['c11']

Comment: As I've mentioned in the problem description, I have ~10 columns in the df2. I do not feel like this would be the correct way.